# need help fixing css for IE6 >_<

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I am working on the following page: [www.darksnippets.com](http://www.darksnippets.com/)

It looks good on FF and chrome but on IE6 the width looks terrible for the home page and other pages. for example: http://www.darksnippets.com/?page_id=62 on IE6 is extra wide.

I cant seem to fix this issue. I  know the site is using tables rather than div's but I've grandfathered this in.  Would just like some ninja style IE6 fix.

Comment: This isn't an answer but it might help. http://www.virtuosimedia.com/tutorials/ultimate-ie6-cheatsheet-how-to-fix-25-internet-explorer-6-bugs

Comment: doctype.com would be a better site for getting help with these kinds of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this :

```
<body>
<!--[if IE 6]>
<div id="ie6">
<![endif]-->

yourcode

<!--[if IE 6]>
</div>
<![endif]-->
</body>
```

in your css file do this
for example you have this :

```
<div class="header">content</div>
```

the normal css would be :

```
.header{width:100px;}
```

and if you want to ajust it for ie6 you should do :

```
#ie6 .header{width:120px;}
```

so this code :

```
.header{width:100px;}
#ie6 .header{width:120px;}
```

would make your header 100px wide in most of the browsers and in ie6 it would make it 120px.

Don`t forget. Use Css

Answer (score 0):

The first table in your code has a 100% width. Shouldn't be too tough to set it's width to 800px (or whatever your page width is) and center it so stuff doesn't break out of that.